# Deny extension with htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, nginx, http-status-code-403

I want to give 403 error to specific extension if someone try to access it directly or try to include my file in third-party website/ cross website.

Example :

let say, `example.com` is my website and it have a image file happy.png so i want if someone visit example.com/happy.png it should display 403 error and also it should not be used in any other domain like `<img src="http://example.com/happy.png" />` except my domain `example.com`. Only my domain should use my assets.

> i want to deny txt, png, jpg, jpeg, ico, css, js etc

.htaccess code :

```
<FilesMatch ".txt", "png", "css", "js">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```

OR

```
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|psd|log|sh)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

What wrong with my code? why it not working as i want?

Comment: @ChrisHaas No, i want to protect multiple extension just not only images and also i want to do this with .htaccess

Comment: Did you read all of the answers on that page, including the one with an htaccess sample that blocks for missing referrers and supports multiple extensions?

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(txt|ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpeg|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```